# Powershell - convert Windows Eventlog multiline message to single line

Tags: powershell, logging, multiline

**Scenario:** Working PS script traverses multiple folders containing logs (folder name is the name of the originating server), extracting the last line from the last completed log - this works, but in case the last log line is part of a multiline message, I get useless data from this line.

**Question:** How can I implement in the working script a cleanup that puts multiline messages all in one line?

**Working script** ([original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67023194/powershell-create-csv-list-containing-newest-line-in-newest-file-in-n-number-su/67023902#67023902))

```
# List all folders on the Initial Path
$folders = Get-ChildItem D:\Logs | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

$export = [system.collections.generic.list[pscustomobject]]::new()

foreach($folder in $folders)
{
    # Get the newest file in each folder
    $file = Get-ChildItem $folder -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -First 1

    # Read the content of the file and get the last line
    #$content = (Get-Content $file)[-1]
    $content = (Get-Content $file.FullName)[-1]

    # Here you can create a new object that will be used to export to Csv
    # As an example, i'll create an object with the File Name,
    # Last Write Time and Last Line of the Content (This will be the CSV columns)
    $export.Add(
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            DirName=$file.FullName
#            FileName = $file.Name
            LastWriteTime = $file.LastWriteTime
            LastLine = $content
    })
}

# After the loop finishes you can export the results to a Csv
$export | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation D:\export\MyFilelist_LastLogLines.csv
```

Comment: Do you want to preserve/serialize the line breaks so you can recreate the original (multiline) string later?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen no, the line breaks are not needed afterwards. In the subsequent parsing of the loglines I have regex patterns pulling fields 'timestamp', 'hostname', 'ip address' - unfortunately said multiline messages break this regex.

Comment: Is what you want to normalize whitespaces (including newlines) like browsers do? Try `LastLine = $content -replace '[\r\n\s]+', ' '`

Comment: `$content = (Get-Content $file.FullName) -join ' '` ***should*** work :)